# Specific mail notification

Tags: plugin-recommendation, email

I have a sport site, where every user who registers is a collaborator by default, and when he writes an article, the people I want can approve it.
This is what I want:
If someone writes an article about soccer (which is a category), only the editors that I want (so every editor which is subscribed in soccer) will receive an email with a link to approve and publish the article.
Is there a plugin for it? I'm using Email Alerts, which do the job, but send to everyone the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin that *(in my opinion)* will do just the job for you.

It is the ["Peter's Collaboration E-mails"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-collaboration-e-mails/). You can find it in the WordPress plugins repository.

From the plugin's description:

*"You can create groups of Contributor users and assign different moderators for each group. In other words, different users can be notified based on who wrote a post. You can also assign moderators based on various taxonomies (such as tags, categories, and more) on post, pages, and custom post types. If a Contributor user belongs to multiple groups and/or a post has multiple taxonomy values, all moderators who have been assigned to the relevant groups or who match the post type rules are e-mailed."*

I hope that helps.

Comment: Just perfect. Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Ettore Nice. Glad I could help. :)